How to change navbarTab's font color in bs4Dash
I'm building a dashboard using the bs4Dash R package. I want my navbar to be colored, that's why I specified status = "primary" in the dashboardHeader() parameter and color = "primary" in the dashboardBrand() parameter.
My code looks like this
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(fresh)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "Title",
  dark = NULL,
  help = NULL,
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  header = dashboardHeader(
    status = "primary",
    title = dashboardBrand(
      title = "My Dashboard",
      color = "primary"
    ),
    navbarMenu(
      id = "navmenu",
      navbarTab(tabName = "Item 1", text = "Item 1"),
      navbarTab(
        text = "Items",
        dropdownHeader("List"),
        navbarTab(tabName = "Sub Item 2", text = "Sub Item 2"),
        navbarTab(tabName = "Sub Item 3", text = "Sub Item 3"),
        navbarTab(tabName = "Sub Item 4", text = "Sub Item 4"),
        navbarTab(tabName = "Sub Item 5", text = "Sub Item 5"),
        navbarTab(tabName = "Sub Item 6", text = "Sub Item 6")
      ),
      navbarTab(tabName = "Item 7", text = "Item 7"),
      navbarTab(tabName = "Item 8", text = "Item 8")
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

The color of the navbar is alright, the problem is that now the color of the text in my dropdown tabs are not visible. I think they are white to match the color of the other tabs (white on blue background).

Let's say i want the color of the text in the dropdown menu to be green, how can i change its color? And which parameter should i tweak to change in yellow the color of the other navbarTabs (only the ones in the navbar, not the ones in the dropdown menu)?

This looks like a bug that could be reported on the Github page: https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash/issues/
In the mean time, you could edit the color of menu/submenu items by inserting some CSS in the body:
 body = dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .nav-link {
        color: yellow !important;
      }
      .dropdown-menu .nav-link {
        color: green !important;
      }"
      ))
    ),
#...

